# Ember Bootstrap plugin

Tags: ember.js

I am using the Bootstrap Table plugin with Ember. When I execute the following code it works:

HBS

```
<table id="table" class="header-fixed"></table>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('#table').bootstrapTable({{jsonHelper table}});
</script>
```

But I am trying to move all my javascript out of the temmplate and into the javascript file. The following does not work:

HBS

```
<table id="table" class="header-fixed"></table>
```

JS

```
didInsertElement: function() {
  this.$('#table').bootstrapTable(this.get('table'));
}
```

I receive the following error: `Uncaught TypeError: this.$(...).bootstrapTable is not a function`.

I have the following in my `ember-cli-build.js`:

```
app.import('bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js');
app.import('bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css');
app.import('bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js');
app.import('bower_components/bootstrap-table/dist/bootstrap-table.min.css');
app.import('bower_components/bootstrap-table/dist/bootstrap-table.min.js');
```

So it should be importing bootstrapTable. It clearly is importing because it works when I execute the command from the template file. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does your jquery selector work?

Comment: Yes, it works fine in both cases.

Comment: Did you restart the server? Try sticking a `debugger;` inside `didInsertElement` and checking that `this.$('#table')` returns what you're expecting. Your code seems fine at a first read.

Comment: I am getting somewhere... For the HBS implementation, the selector returns: `__proto__: n[0]`. For the JS implementation, the selector returns: `__proto__: jQuery[0]`. Any idea why?

Comment: `__proto__: n[0]` contains `bootstrapTable`. `__proto__: jQuery[0]` does not.